# Error message when using ./configure in reaver

Tags: bash

Whenever I type

```
./configure
```

i get this error message:

```
./configure line 1633: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 1643: config.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: You're doing this in a directory you cannot write to. Post output of `ls -ld .` and `id`.

Comment: reaver : `sudo apt install reaver` .... Building applications : The default build folder is `/home/[name]/tmp/`